# how to call a function of vf page script from vf page controller

Tags: visualforce, javascript, controller

I have a VF page and in script tag of that VF page I have a function. Now I want to call that function from VF page Controller. How can I call VF page script function from its Controller bcoz i want to pass argument from component to script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible.